# chromeapp clear all notifications

Tags: google-chrome, notifications, google-chrome-app

I am trying to create a chromeapp that, when a hotkey is pressed, clears all notifications. I have the hotkey set up and working, but I can't seem to get the `chrome.notifications.clear` api to work, and I think it is because I can't/don't know how to get all notification ids. Is there any way to clear a notification without knowing its id, or just clear all notifications? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/notifications#method-clear),
you need to get the notificationId to delete the notification.

The `chrome.notifications.clear(string notificationId, function callback)` it only clears a specified notification.

The id of the notification to be cleared is returned by `notification.create` method.

So if you dont know the notificationId in the system, you can get it by calling the `chrome.notifications.getAll(function callback)`. It retrieves all the notification and notificationId in the system.

Answer (score 4):

If someone still needs a code example:

```
chrome.notifications.getAll((items) => {
  if ( items ) {
      for (let key in items) {
          chrome.notifications.clear(key);
      }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if by "all notifications" you mean notifications created outside your chrome extension like from a different website, chrome API does only give you access to notifications created within your extension, therefore `chrome.notifications.getAll` won't really get you all the notifications except those created by you.